# Will android geofences work without network connection and just with GPS on?

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, android-location, android-geofence

I am trying to store the data of geofence transitions (geofence intime and geofence outtime) when the network connection is not available and preferably send them to server when network connection becomes available. But before doing that I would like to know if I could get the geofence transition without any network connection. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it should work without network connection using GPS & Triangulation. I will recommend you turn WiFi on also because even do it doesn't need to be connected, if WiFi is on it can estimate also the location based on the WiFi's near by.

If you want a demo to test without any network connection try this app:

[Geofence sample application](https://www.dropbox.com/s/on0hzznwmkkw4o3/domaven.crossgeofencesample.apk?dl=0)

Comment: Did you develop this app?  Any chance you can post the source code?  I'm having a similar issue where a phone geofence is working fine, but a tablet without data it has GPS is not working.  However, that sample app does work on the tablet.  Not sure where I'm going wrong.